# Asp.Net MVC 5 Jquery validation not working on ajax post with submit event, showing as valid form

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have added all the required things regarding to client side validation but validation is not working.

Please help me find which thing I have missed or what I am doing wrong.

I have added all the required thing as below:

BundleConfig.cs

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));


bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js",
                  "~/Scripts/umd/popper.min.js"));
```

View:

```
@model WebApplication1.Areas.Users.Models.MyViewModel
<div>
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("detail", "mycontroller", null, FormMethod.Post, new { @Id="myForm", @class = "form-horizontal" }))
        {
        <!-- Modal Header -->
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Unit Type</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            </div>
        <!-- Modal body -->
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="full-wdth clearfix otp-section">
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
                    <div id="validation-summary"></div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "main-label requiredasterisk" })

                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control form-control-sm", placeholder = "Name", maxlength = "50" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <!-- Modal footer -->
            <div class="modal-footer customMargin">
                <button data-dismiss="modal" id="btn-cancel" class="btn btn-default" type="button">Cancel</button>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-submit" type="submit">
                    Submit
                </button>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

Layout.cshtml

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery", "~/bundles/jqueryval", "~/bundles/bootstrap")
```

WebConfig.cs:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

on browser HTML page showing the JS files:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/perfect-scrollbar/perfect-scrollbar.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/XXXXXX.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/XXXXXXXX.js"></script>
```

Before submit on browser the HTML code:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="main-label requiredasterisk" for="Name">Name</label>    
   <input class="form-control form-control-sm" data-val="true" data-val-required="The name is required" id="Name" maxlength="50" name="Name" placeholder="Name" type="text" value="">
   <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Name" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</div>
```

After press submit button:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="main-label requiredasterisk" for="Name">Name</label>    
  <input class="form-control form-control-sm valid" data-val="true" data-val-required="The name is required" id="Name" maxlength="50" name="Name" placeholder="Name" type="text" value="">
   <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Name" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</div>
```

MyViewModel.cs:

```
public class MyViewModel
{            
    /// <summary>
    /// Id 
    /// </summary>
    public int Id { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// name
    /// </summary>
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The name is required")]
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }    
}
```

Jquery:

```
var BindFormSubmit = function (formControl, options) {
    "use strict";
    var settings = {};
    settings = $.extend({}, settings, options);
    formControl.validate(settings.validateSettings);
    formControl.submit(function (e) {
        var formdata = new FormData();         
        $.each(formControl.serializeArray(), function (i, item) {
            formdata.append(item.name, item.value);
        });


        var submitBtn = formControl.find(':submit');
        if (formControl.validate().valid()) {             
            $.ajax(formControl.attr("action"), {
                type: "POST",
                data: formdata,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function (result) {

                    //on success
                }
            });
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    return formControl;
};


BindFormSubmit($("#myForm"), { updateTargetId: "validation-summary" });
```

Comment: How are you rendering the modal? Are you using ajax? If you are then have a look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23930787/form-validation-is-not-working-for-dynamic-dialog-content

Comment: Did you checked that you have the Nuget package installed?

Comment: @JonathanOrtega I have created default template application with auth can you please let me know which additional Nuget packages required to validate the form?

Comment: @KevDevMan Yeah, I'm validating the form using formElement.validate().valid() and also formElement.valid() but in both case it's return true (mean as valid form).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All things are correct except the binding the client side submit event with validation setting.

Because

```
formControl.validate(settings.validateSettings);
```

is overriding the validation and preventing the default MVC validation so, I have to comment the above code statement as below and it will work perfectly.

```
var BindFormSubmit = function (formControl, options) {
    "use strict";
    var settings = {};
    settings = $.extend({}, settings, options);
    //formControl.validate(settings.validateSettings);
    formControl.submit(function (e) {
        var formdata = new FormData();         
        $.each(formControl.serializeArray(), function (i, item) {
            formdata.append(item.name, item.value);
        });


        var submitBtn = formControl.find(':submit');
        if (formControl.validate().valid()) {             
            $.ajax(formControl.attr("action"), {
                type: "POST",
                data: formdata,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function (result) {

                    //on success
                }
            });
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    return formControl;
};


BindFormSubmit($("#myForm"), { updateTargetId: "validation-summary" });
```